# I am looking for a webbased text editor that supports collaboration

Tags: ajax, text-editor, collaboration

I am looking for a web based text editor that supports collaboration with 2 or more people.

I am hoping to work on a fairly 'small' project with a couple other people from afar and would really like for us to be able to work on the same file at the same time and see the changes each other make in 'real time'.

Language built on is not much of an issue, would prefer to have syntax highlighting, but not really required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[google docs](http://docs.google.com) would be a save bet. it allows for simultanous editing.

Answer (score 5):

[EtherPad](http://etherpad.com) is ideal for realtime collaborative editing, much better than [google docs](http://docs.google.com) if you're ok with strictly plain text.

Try it out here:  http://etherpad.org/

I just tried out [CollabEdit](http://collabedit.com) for comparison and it seems it really can't handle two people typing at the same time.

See also these similar questions:

- [How do you collaborate with other coders in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510163/how-do-you-collaborate)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148538/what-is-a-great-tool-for-remote-pair
- [What Features Should Tomorrow's Wiki Include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457211/what-features-should-tomorrows-wiki)

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Bespin](http://bespin.mozilla.com) the new one from Mozilla! It is supposed to have collaboration tools built in, Though I'm not sure if all the features are available yet.

Comment: Im just looking at it now... looks exciting

Answer (score 3):

[CollabEdit](http://www.collabedit.com/)

I saw this linked in another question and it seems to fit the bill 100%, web-based and syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html)?  Myself and two others were using the spreadsheet for planning on a project.  You can see the other people moving around their curors and entering text.  It's very very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Look at  [DocSynch](http://docsynch.sourceforge.net/)

I saw demo of the plugin for eclipse, i dont' remember it's name... maybe [this one](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/RT_Shared_Editing)

Also [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor) has a list of the collaborative editors.

Answer (score 0):

I hear Mozilla's new "cloud" text editor, [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/), looks interesting.